# Mail for Exchange confirmation android 2.2 device

Tags: android, device-admin

I would like to ask what kind of support is provided for "Microsoft Mail for exchange" on android 2.2 devices and onwards.

Question:

1. Can developers setup an exchange account programmatically?
2. Are there API's to access an exchange server?
3. It is included on the [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) as one of the examples that benefits Device Admin but it didn't include emails on the example. Where can we find examples and resources about this one?
4. Does this also support for other IMAP or POP3 accounts?

Thanks